# How to find out more on error in merge replication in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

Error that we are getting is:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 8114)

This kind of error is not so descriptive so we don't know where to look next. **Does anybody know where to look on more descriptive error then this. I mean a system table that holds more info or a view.**

We have all objects in replication.

Thank you

Comment: How long has the merge replication been working before this error? Did anything change? Service Pack, etc? Very broad error to know what's going on... Check Windows SQL Server App log? But, look here... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c3edf023-8fa6-4d99-b6a1-cab28a591b01/replication-issue-error-converting-data-type-nvarchar-to-numeric?forum=sqlreplication

Comment: @WEI_DBA it was running for some time, maybe hours or days, but really the question is why Microsoft doesn't add more details to it like this or that object, I think it wouldn't hurt anyone if they do.

Comment: Totally agree. Good luck. Hope the link points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Run profiler on the subscriber with the errors collection. See where it is failing. It should be obvious from there what stored procedure or object is causing the error. Paste the name of the object back here. If it is a table post the table script here. If it is a stored procedure you should be able to see the name of the table embedded in the stored procedure name.

[microsoft blog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c3edf023-8fa6-4d99-b6a1-cab28a591b01/replication-issue-error-converting-data-type-nvarchar-to-numeric?forum=sqlreplication)